# How can I define pointer to the struct?

Tags: c

I would like to define to the struct

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned long GPFSEL[6];
    unsigned long Reserved_1;
    unsigned long GPSET[2];
    unsigned long Reserved_2;

//Ignoring the reserved and test bytes
} GPIO_REGS_;
```

One solution would be this

```
volatile  GPIO_REGS_ * const GPIO_REGS  = ((volatile GPIO_REGS_ *) 0x20200000UL);
```

In this case I can reach the register as follow:

```
GPIO_REGS->GPSET[0];
```

But how should I define the GPIO_REGS variable that I can use as follow

```
GPIO_REGS.GPSET[0];
```

Why the following won't work?

```
#define GPIO_REGS  (*(( GPIO_REGS_ *) 0x20200000UL));
```

Comment: Why would you want to? Whats so wrong with `->` or `(*GPIO_REGS).`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code in your question

```
#define GPIO_REGS  (*(( GPIO_REGS_ *) 0x20200000UL));
```

is the semicolon at the end.   You should remove it

```
#define GPIO_REGS  (*(( GPIO_REGS_ *) 0x20200000UL))
```

(The real lesson here is to avoid macros at all costs.  They are notoriously tricky.  Every time you think you understand them, you just get a false sense of security and then more buggy code is written!)

Anyway,  with your original use of the macro:

```
GPIO_REGS.GPSET[0];
```

it was expanded as:

```
(*(( GPIO_REGS_ *) 0x20200000UL));.GPSET[0];
```

See that the semicolon doesn't fit here?

Keep your macros small.   Don't put `;` on the end.  And always put brackets around them.  The brackets should be the outermost thing - do not put a semicolon on the end.  (We could write other warnings about macros all day long.

Answer (score 1):

```
GPIO_REGS_ my_gpio_reg;

GPIO_REGS_ * my_gpio_reg_ptr;

my_gpio_reg_ptr = &my_gpio_reg;
```